# How to schedule an email to be sent every Monday with data from google firebase in the email body using nodeJs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Like the title suggests, how do I schedule a function to run every fixed interval and it will send an email to any email address I specify?

I want to use a node server to send emails using nodemailer to my SMTP server.

I made a system that stores fault reported by the mobile application onto google firebase realtime database. Whenever a new fault is reported, my nodeJs server will send an email using node mailer to the smtp server. What I want to achieve now is to have a scheduled email delivery system of certain objects in the database. Like for example, every Monday at 10 sent all objects ref 'a' onchild 'unsent' to xyz@mail.com . Any ideas or comments are appreciated.

What I have researched is google scheduler using cron schedule expressions, I thought maybe I could have it send something to an endpoint in the server, and then from there the node server will get filtered data from firebase and send it to the SMTP server. But I am really noob in programming and don't really know how to design or execute a structure like that.

Comment: I've solved this issue but I can't post answers to this question. some resources to help anyone who needs to solve this would be https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron - to schedule the jobs you want to execute, https://crontab.guru/ - to get the syntax

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct you want to run some job at a specific time of day or week on a NodeJS server. These jobs are called `Cron Jobs`. there are npm modules for Cron Jobs.

1. [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)
2. [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)

you can use these modules to run your jobs then fetch the data and then I think you can easily filter the data and with the help of [nodemailer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer) npm module you can send the mail.

[Here](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-in-node-js-897215e2e5d3)  you can see an example for the Cron jobs in the NodeJS server.

Comment: thanks for giving something to search on google with, definitely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which will fetch data from firebase and also send the email. To send the email, you will need to install `nodemailer` and also turn ON "Less Secure App Access" for the sender email address. Searching those keywords on google will lead you there.

You could do something like

```
async function sendMail() {
    // fetch required data from database
    let transport = mailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 587,
        secure: false,
        auth: {
            user: 'your_source_email_address',
            pass: 'password'
        },
    });
    const message = {
        from: '', // Sender address
        to: ['email1', 'email2'...],   // List of recipients
        subject: '', // Subject line
        html: '<!DOCTYPE html>' +
            '<html lang="en">' +
            '<head>' +
            '<meta charset="UTF-8">' +
            '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">' +
            '</head>' +
            '<body>' +
            Your data to be displayed in silmilar html format or link an html file.
            '</body>' +
            '</html>'
    };
}
```

As for scheduling it for every Monday at 10:00, you can install `node-cron` and configure it like this in your entry file:

```
 const cron = require('node-cron');
    ...
    ...

 cron.schedule('0 10 * * Monday', async () => {
    await sendMail(
}, {
    scheduled: true,
    timezone: 'your_time_zone'
});
```

More info for your timezone and examples for scheduling are available on their [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron).

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: yes it really did help me for the cron scheduling part, now i am atleast able to console.log my snapshots from fire base, thanks a bunch!